# Writing a function that mimics a REPL in IDLE:

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to write an internal REPL in IDLE that logs everything to a text file.

So something like

```
def myrepl():
    myinput = ''
    with open("myrepl.txt", "a") as log:
        while not myinput == "EXIT":
            myinput = input("Enter an expression to evaluate.\n")
            log.write(myinput + "\n")
            if myinput == "EXIT":
                break
            eval(myinput)
            print(eval(myinput))
            log.write(str(eval(myinput)) + "\n")
```

This returns errors when I, say, import things. eval() also gives an error when I try to do assignments. The REPL also breaks when I enter something incorrect.

Is there a way to handle these exceptions? If so, how? Also, is there a way to capture eval()'s output as strings? Taking `str(eval("print(0)"))`, for example, yields an additional `None`.